# datamash tool : transposition rows->columns and inversely - Shortcut with vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-columns, rows

I have just discovered the tool `datamash` to swap between transposition of rows/columns or columns/rows.

How can I define a shortcut in `~/.vimrc` to automatically transpose in the 2 senses ?

I tried to set (delimiter is whitespace) : `noremap <C-T><C-T> :% !datamash transpose -W`

I don't know how to specify the current opened file on which I want to toggle between the rows/columns ans inversely columns/rows.

Anyone could see how to perform this transposition by a simple shortcut on `vim` ?

**EDIT:** everyting works fine by setting into ~/.vimrc:

```
noremap <C-T><C-T> :% !datamash --no-strict transpose -W<CR>
```

Comment: Isn't really there anyone who could help me to set a shortcut that transposes in the 2 senses an array, for example :  (3x2)----> (2x3) and (2x3) ----> (3x2) ?

Comment: You could try looking at https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Suppressing_file_changed_warnings_in_a_specific_buffer

Comment: @jeremysprofile. Thanks for your quick answer. This is a little tricky, I wonder if there is not a simpler solution.

Comment: What do you mean by the current buffer? My `:map þ :% !datamash transpose -W<CR>` seems to be working as intended.

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto . Thanks for your answer ! , it works perfectly. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including `<CR>` by the end of the `noremap` line.